# OxyPlot how to add Points to DataPoint?

Tags: oxyplot

i have a plotmodel with 2 different lineSeries. 
In the first lineSeries can be values between 1000 and 10000.
In the second lineSeries are values between 1 and 10.

So when i plot this I can see the first lineSeries very well, but the second one is just at the bottom.

So I defined two different LinearAxis, one for the right and one for the left side.

```
 m.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left,Minimum = 0, Maximum = maxPointValue1 });
 m.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Right, Minimum = 0, Maximum = maxPointValue2 });
```

Is it possible to bind the first series to the left LinearAxis and the second to the right Axis?

So that the second series is not at the bottom?

Thanks in advance

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is my friend.

On your second axis, this case your right, you need to define a key.

```
var rightAxis = new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis()
{
    Key = "secondary",
    Position = AxisPosition.Right,
    // And then the rest
}
```

Now when you include a series, you give that the same key

```
yourLineSeries.XAxisKey = "secondary";
```

Now when your series is added, it should use your right axis.

Hope this helps!